# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), Cant find why

Tags: php, foreach

I am a beginner level php programmer. I was trying to use the MVC but I can't even get past the testing of this one.

Problem: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in httpdocs/data/serieDAO.php on line 15

Can anyone give me a tip to what is causing this problem?

The code (sorry if it is very long):

/index.php

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// main controller
require_once ("business/serieservice.php");
$service = new SerieService();
$serielijst = $service->toonAlleSeries();
include("test/test1.php");
?>
```

/business/serieservice.php

```
<?php
require_once("data/serieDAO.php");
class SerieService{

    public function toonAlleSeries(){
        $serieDAO = new SerieDAO();
        $lijst = $serieDAO->displayList();
        return $lijst;
    }
}
?>
```

/data/serieDAO.php

```
 <?php
require_once("entities/series.class.php");

class SerieDAO{

    // public function __construct(){
        // $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tvseasons", "seasons", "bompa");
    // }

    public function displayList(){
        $list = array();
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tvseasons", "seasons", "bompa");
        $sql = "select id, title, desc, url, genre, trailer from Series";
        $resultSet = $dbh->query($sql);
        foreach ($resultSet as $row){
            $serie = new Series($row["id"], $row["title"],$row["desc"], $row["url"], $row["genre"], $row["trailer"]);
            array_push($list, $serie);
        }
        $dbh = null;        
        return $list;
    }


}
?>
```

/entities/series.class.php

```
<?
//class met getters en setters van series entity
class Series{
  private $id;
  private $title;
  private $desc; //description
  private $url;
  private $genre;
  private $trailer;

  /* Try to figure out how to determine the $id. Cannot be set obviosly but get should be possible */

  //setters
  function setTitle ($title){
    $this->title = $title;
  }
  function setDesc($desc){
    $this->desc = $desc;
  }
  function setUrl($url){
    $this->url = $url;
  }
  function setGenre($genre){
    $this->genre = $genre;
  }
  function setTrailer($trailer){
    $this->trailer = $trailer;
  }

  //getters
  function getTitle(){
    return $this->title;
  }
  function getDesc(){
    return $this->desc;
  }
    function getUrl(){
    return $this->url;
  }
    function getGenre(){
    return $this->genre;
  }
    function getTrailer(){
    return $this->trailer;
  }
}
?>
```

/test/test1.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test1 lijst series</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Een lijst van alle series</h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($serielijst as $serie){
 print ("<li>bla bla</li>");
}
?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

edit: I know the code Inside the foreach is not working yet. But I already figured out that that is not the cause.

Comment: Do you ever check whether you get any results from your DB queries? Foreach is expecting an array, it's not getting it. Check where arrays are created and what might fail.

Comment: Use try/catch when creating a PDO object, so you can see any exception raised. Also try and post only the relevant part of the code.

Comment: Go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php for information on error checking. Like they said, make sure your query actually returns something.

Comment: Back when I still did php i did this to get the values out of each row

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}

Comment: @Jarco: It's failing, because you are using a reserved word on your query, check my answer for a solution.

Comment: @Jarco Consider reducing your code to the *smallest non-working example you can think of* for your next question. Not only is it rude to practically force people to read 100 lines of code where 96 have nothing whatsoever to do with the issue, reducing code to the problematic section helps *you* understand the problem and *others* to reproduce it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is failing to return an array with the result-set, because you are using a reserved word (`desc`) for one of the table columns.

Change:

```
$sql = "select id, title, desc, url, genre, trailer from Series";
```

to:

```
$sql = "select id, title, `desc`, url, genre, trailer from Series";
```

Comment: I just found that out also by running the query in phpmyadmin. Good tip to fix it. thx

Answer (score 1):

The error typically means that the argument for the foreach is not an array, or an empty array. You can try to look at the contents of your $resultSet by doing `var_dump($resultSet)`. I'm guessing you're getting an empty reply from MySQL which is resulting in that error. To verify that, you should attempt to run the query manually.

Comment: Ive done it manually. U are correct the error is there.
desc is reserved in sql. I should have known ...

Answer (score 0):

Please vardump $resultSet variable and see if it is an array. Foreach method excepts only arrays and thus, it will throw an error is it is supplied with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like either the connection or the query fails. Try the following to see what is wrong:

```
if ($resultSet) {
        foreach ($resultSet as $row){
            $serie = new Series($row["id"], $row["title"],$row["desc"], $row["url"], $row["genre"], $row["trailer"]);
            array_push($list, $serie);
        }
else {
    var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

may be $resultSet is not array. 
it may happen because sometimes query doesnot get data .

you should add this condition before foreach loop

if(is_array($resultSet) && count($resultSet)>0){

```
foreach($resultSet as $row){
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not fetch the datas in /data/serieDAO.php, like this :

```
     $resultSet = $dbh->query($sql);
     $rows = $resultSet->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // this looks missing in your code
    foreach($rows as $key => $value) {
        $data_array[$key] = $value;// replace with your "serie" stuffs
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tvseasons", "seasons", "bompa"); 
 $sql = "select id, title, desc, url, genre, trailer from Series";
```

check these lines, your connection may have error, or check your query which matches your table fields. check manually, is the select query is executing.